# Specifying color for geom bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, geom-bar

My data frame is as follows

```
   School Gender Value ColorGroup
1 School1   Male    10      1Male
2 School1 Female    30    1Female
3 School2   Male    40      1Male
4 School2 Female    70    1Female
5 School3   Male     5      2Male
6 School3 Female    90    2Female
```

I can create the following bar charts

```
ggplot(data=data2, aes(x=School, y=Value, group = Gender, fill = Gender)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), width =  0.5)

ggplot(data=data2, aes(x=School, y=Value, group = Gender, fill = ColorGroup)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), width =  0.5)
```

1. Bar chart 1 - Grouped by Gender
   [image]
2. Barchart 2 - grouped by ColorGroup
   [image]

What I wish to do is specify the colors as follows
School3 to have different colors from School1 and School2 using the following code

```
cols33 <- c("1Male" = "yellow", "1Female" = "orange", "2Male" = "red", "2Female" = "blue") 

ggplot(data=data2, aes(x=School, y=Value, group = Gender,fill = ColorGroup)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), width =  0.5) + 
  scale_color_manual(name="",values=cols33)
```

but I still get the same output as barchart2.
[image]

Please can you help understand why the scale_color_manual is not being honored in my code.

Comment: `fill != color`

Comment: Hi @Henrik -  I could not follow your comment, using `fill != color` will not apply any colors to the bar charts.

Comment: You have mapped **`fill`** color in `aes`. Thus, you need to use `scale_fill_manual`, not `scale_color_manual`.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Henrik that helped solve the problem. I am going to make the change now. Following my example, would you know If there is an easy way to only show two out of the four legends, essentially only show legends for School3 from my example

Comment: Please take your time to study the help texts, it's all in there.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171826/discussion-between-vik-g-and-henrik).

Comment: I might be missing something, but all three plots look identical...?

Comment: Hi @camille - my question was answered by Henrik's suggestion. I had a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548030/removing-two-legends-out-of-four-from-ggplot2) about  removing some of the legends, if you have any ideas on how I can do that, it would be really helpful

Comment: @VikG Clearly you didn't bother to read `?scale_fill_manual` as I suggested: "# As with other scales you can use `breaks` to control the appearance of the legend."

Answer (score 0):

I had mapped fill color in aes. Thus, needed to use `scale_fill_manual`, not `scale_color_manual`.